# Problems to deploy django in heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Follow the log:

```
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318884+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318885+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318888+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318886+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318888+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318890+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318885+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318893+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318895+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318889+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318891+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318892+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/redewebsite/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
2016-03-05T15:09:05.319022+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-05 15:09:05 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318890+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318894+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318896+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318897+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._setup(name)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324196+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-05 15:09:05 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318892+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318896+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324211+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324212+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324213+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324215+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318894+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318898+00:00 app[web.1]:     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324216+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318898+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324216+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324221+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324219+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/redewebsite/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
2016-03-05T15:09:05.318899+00:00 app[web.1]: ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324222+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324208+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324213+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324214+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324210+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324211+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324218+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324214+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324220+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324224+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._setup(name)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324217+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324218+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324220+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324251+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324225+00:00 app[web.1]:     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324250+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324248+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324226+00:00 app[web.1]: ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324252+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324224+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324250+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324255+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324222+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324223+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324255+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324253+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324254+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324251+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324252+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324254+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324256+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324258+00:00 app[web.1]:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324259+00:00 app[web.1]:     django.setup()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324259+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324260+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324261+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324257+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324258+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/redewebsite/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324264+00:00 app[web.1]: ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
2016-03-05T15:09:05.382734+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324257+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324261+00:00 app[web.1]:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324262+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324262+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._setup(name)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324263+00:00 app[web.1]:     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383454+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383456+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 206, in run
2016-03-05T15:09:05.324374+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-03-05 15:09:05 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.382767+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383460+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 219, in handle_chld
2016-03-05T15:09:05.382753+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383455+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383460+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383457+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 302, in halt
2016-03-05T15:09:05.382793+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383457+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383458+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383459+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 347, in stop
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383462+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2016-03-05T15:09:05.382834+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.382860+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 192, in run
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383453+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383461+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383462+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 464, in reap_workers
2016-03-05T15:09:05.383463+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2016-03-05T15:09:06.271890+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-03-05T15:09:06.284071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-03-05T15:09:08.486440+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=redewebsite.herokuapp.com request_id=083bbcbc-0cac-459b-af5b-c7ea9f59e080 fwd="189.48.111.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-05T15:10:17.486279+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=redewebsite.herokuapp.com request_id=64746251-2419-4525-b257-695effd9f15d fwd="189.48.111.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

When I run `heroku open`, return-me 503 and the message:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Someone could help me?

Comment: what is your Procfile config like?

Comment: My Procfile is just: `web: gunicorn redewebsite.wsgi --log-file -`